# Trying to get a response from xml on an iis7 server

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm trying to display the version info in a web page on an IIS7 server. I really have no clue what I'm doing, but I would like this to be processed server side, and I'm assuming that means using some variation of asp. I know how to use php to do something similar, but that's not an option for this project. The xml document is coming from a local resource on the same server using the following url:

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/webservice/rm-agent/v1/monitor/devices?scope%3Dequipment
```

and the output of the in chrome looks like this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<DEVICES count="3" time="13-10-12 16:29:20">
<VIEW name="all" scope="equipment">
<DEVICE mac_address="88:E0:F3:20:08:B9" model="WLC2" system_ip="192.168.1.99/24" sw_version="8.0.3.6.0" location="""" name="WLC2" license="WLAN Access Points:4Adv Voice:1Mesh/Bridging:4High-Availability:1Spectrum Analysis:4" object-id="com.trapeze.appl.shared.mdl.Chassis: 28660" contact="" serial_number="KE3211500127"/>
<DEVICE mac_address="f8:c0:01:ab:54:c0" model="WLA532-US" system_ip="192.168.1.75" name="name-WLA1" object-id="com.trapeze.appl.shared.mdl.DistributedAP: 29143" serial_number="jb0212039600">
<RADIOS_INFO radio_1_type="802.11ng" radio_2_mac_address="f8:c0:01:ab:54:c1" radio_2_type="802.11na" radio_1_mac_address="f8:c0:01:ab:54:c0"/>
</DEVICE>
<DEVICE mac_address="ac:4b:c8:02:68:00" model="WLA532-US" system_ip="192.168.1.82" name="WLA9999" object-id="com.trapeze.appl.shared.mdl.DistributedAP: 167425" serial_number="jb0212294341">
<RADIOS_INFO radio_1_type="802.11ng" radio_2_mac_address="ac:4b:c8:02:68:01" radio_2_type="802.11na" radio_1_mac_address="ac:4b:c8:02:68:00"/>
</DEVICE>
</VIEW>
</DEVICES>
```

I really just need an html page that shows the sw_version from the first response element, so it would basically just be a page that says:

```
8.0.3.6.0
```

Another problem is that I'm forced to use a https url to request the info, but I don't have the ability to install a proper certificate, so the certificate needs to be ignored as well.

this is what I have tried so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate( object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors ) { return true; }; %>

<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  string url = @"https://127.0.0.1:8443/webservice/rm-agent/v1/monitor/devices?scope%3Dequipment";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(url);

  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <pre>
        <asp:Literal ID="lit1" runat="server" />
      </pre>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't get the load to ignore the certificate warning, and I get a parse error on that line.

Comment: I have tried searching the web for the solution, but for one i dont understand the c# constructs vs the xobject ones. I also don't get why they sometimes say aspx and sometimes asp.net so I'm not entirely sure what i should be searching on. I have tried searching around for a few hours and have gone through about 15 different tries and can't seem to get it. When i do get the xml to load, the problem I have is that it doesn't load because of the certificate error and i can't figure out how to ignore that either.

Comment: I don't use ASP, and I'm not a coder. I wanted a page that will help people trying to connect to a remote evaluation service to know what revision they need to be on dynamically so that they can connect to the system without problems. While I appreciate that you think I should learn ASP.NET, I really have no interest in doing so as it has nothing to do with the line of work I'm in and I honestly have already wasted several hours on something that for me seems like it should be fairly straight forward and simple to do. Anyway, sorry for the poorly formatted request.

Comment: BTW, try putting that `ServicePointManager` stuff as the first line of `Page_Load`. You have it written as though it were a page directive, and it's not.

Comment: I had tried that as well, just wasn't sure where to stick it so was trying it in different spots and that was the last thing I had happened to have tried. When I place it there I get a "does not exist in the current context" compilation error. Also, I believe this should be straightforward because I could have figured out how to do this in php already, mostly because I'm familar with that language though i suppose. In addition, I never said that this wasn't programming, I said that I am not a "coder" and that programming languages are not my day job. They're not my night job either. Thanks.

Comment: Try `System.Net.ServicePointManager`, and put it in the `Page_Load`.

Comment: ah, no errors now! now I just need to figure out how to process that string out of the xml, but hopefully I can find something on the internet for that. Thank you so much!

Comment: What site do you suggest for getting someone to program it for me? Also, I did ask here, it was part of this initial request :P

Comment: I wouldn't use an Internet site to find developers, in general, unless there's no local developer community. As to your request, narrow it down to just the XML part - leave off the irrelevant parts (ASP.NET, etc) and just post the XML part of the problem.

Comment: well, to be honest, I haven't done my due diligence on that part since I wasn't able to get the file successfully to open in the first place, so I'll mess around with that a bit more on my own for now. I generally try to avoid asking for help if I think I can avoid it. But just so I don't mess up again, should I create a new post or edit this existing one if I wind up getting stuck again? Also, when I find the solution to my problem, should I edit my original post and post it? Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: Sorry to ask another stupid question, but again, this is due to my complete lack of understanding ASP. If I wanted to process the XML in an aspx page, then why would the ASP.NET portion be irrelevant when making the post?

Comment: The ASP.NET part would be irrelevant because it will be the same XML code regardless of whether or not it is in an ASPX page. Keep it simple. Also, create a new question. This is a Q&A site, not a forum with threads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @John Saunders for the help getting the request to ignore the certificate warning.
I was unable to get the XML to parse, I think because it was in a weird format from the source, or more likely because I have no clue what I'm doing, but I got it working, so that's all I care about :D
Here is the code that I finally used:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<script runat="server">
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate( object s, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors ) { return true; };
  string url = "https://127.0.0.1:8443/webservice/rm-agent/v1/monitor/devices?scope%3Dequipment";
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(url);
string xmlString = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
string testString = Regex.Match(xmlString, @"sw_version=""([^)]*)"" location").Groups[1].Value;
Response.Write("<center><h2>The Current Version Is:</h2><h1>"+testString+"</h1></center>");
  }
</script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Version</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```